# meaning of "<>" in ADT specification

Tags: abstract-data-type

In reading "Data Structures Using C" (Tenenbaum, Langsam, Augenstein), I've come across an unfamiliar operator in an explanation of abstract data types.

Here's a part specifying rational as an ADT (pg. 14):

```
"
/* value definition*/
abstract typedef <integer, integer> RATIONAL;
condition RATIONAL[1] <> 0;

/*operator definition*/
abstract RATIONAL makerational(a,b)
int a,b;
precondition b<>0;
postcondition makerational[0] == a;
              makerational[1] == b;

abstract RATIONAL add(a,b)
RATIONAL a,b;
postcondition add[1] == a[1] * b[1]
postcondition add[0] == a[0] * b[1] + b[0] * a[1];

..."
```

My understanding is that the overall goal here is to define a rational data type for input integers a over b in terms of legal operations. However, the use of the <> operator on lines 4 and 9 is not clear. What's the meaning of "<>" in this context?

A quick search through the stacks returned no relevant results, but I apologize in advance for a possible repeat.

Comment: I would not call this standard C.

Comment: This is not C, bad tag. In such a spec "<>" means "different" (not equals to). A rational is a couple where the second part cannot be nul. makerational constructor requires the second parameter not to be nul.

Comment: Agreed, not standard C and usually means not equals.

Comment: I thought so, thank you for clarifying. I'll change the tag. What do you suggest as a more appropriate one?

Comment: This is not even non-standard C.

Comment: If that is C I am Mary Poppins.

Comment: @DavidShaked Tag changed

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the book seems to suggest that this code is some kind of low level instruction, but doesn't explicitly define the language. I'm curious to know the identity of the language here... The comment format seems to suggest something a bit C-like, but obviously this isn't C.